# Pandas Basics using Square Brackets

Tags: python

As seen by the code, I am trying to print out my table from the intervals of 0 to when hr1 in the column time is first equal to 1: 01 ( or 1:01 am). I am having a problem with how to implement when hr1 is equal to 1:01 in the square brackets.

```
import pandas as pd 

table = pd.read_csv('2019-01-20.csv')
speed = table['speed_mph']
time = table['timestamp']
x = 1

for hr1 in time: 
  if x < 2: 
    print(table[0:(hr1='1:01')])
    x += 1
```

Comment: Would strongly recommend spending time on reading the documentation about subsetting data here - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

You're bound to keep running into problems like these as you proceed further with your project. Reading the documentation and seeing the examples would help you solve them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would be to use [index](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) to find the first element equal to `1.01`

```
print(table[0:time.index('1:01')+1])
```

I've added one to the result of the `index()` call to include that element. Note that if '1.01' is the last element in the list, this will yield an `IndexError`.

If the element is not found `index()` will raise a `ValueError`.

Note also that you should not use `time` as a variable name, as this shadows the python built-in module of the same name.

I second the comment above, as well. Simply guessing at what the syntax might be will cause a lot of wasted time. You may also find that you get something working by accident, which later on fails with a different data-set.

Answer (score 0):

```
table.iloc[:table[table.timestamp == 'your timestamp'].index[0] + 1]
```

iloc to slice the index, table[table.timestamp == 'your timestamp'].index[0] to return the index of the first match, +1 to include it to the result.

Comment: please add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: .iloc to slice the index, table[table.timestamp == 'your timestamp'].index[0] to return the index of the first match, +1 to include it to the result.